# Zend Framework 3 - Module won't load

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

So i've a web app using Zend Framework 3. It ran perfectly until today. I tried to add a module ("Params") and i can't figure why it doesn't load.

My Module tree :

[image]

My config/Module.config.php :

```
 return [
    'Features',
    'Version',
    'Installs',
    'Tests',
    'Params'

];
```

My composer.json :

```
  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Clients\\": "module/Clients/src/",
            "User\\" : "module/User/src",
            "Connexions\\" : "module/Connexions/src",
            "Groups\\" : "module/Groups/src",
            "Workgroup\\" : "module/Workgroup/src",
            "Projects\\" : "module/Projects/src",
            "Contacts\\" : "module/Contacts/src",
            "Bugs\\" : "module/Bugs/src",
            "Features\\" : "module/Features/src",
            "Version\\" : "module/Version/src",
            "Installs\\" : "module/Installs/src",
            "Tests\\" : "module/Tests/src",
            "Moulinettes\\" : "module/Moulinettes/src",
            "Parameters\\" : "module/Params/src"
        }
    },
```

I've checked every php file in my Params folder for a typo, and there is none.

In my NavManager.php, when i add my params item, i instantly get a Zend Error :

```
$items[] = [
                'id' => 'params',
                'label' => 'Paramètres',
                'icone' => 'settings',
                //'link' => $url('params')
```

[image]

Any help appreciated ! :)

i tried to duplicate an existing and working module => Didn't work
I tried to start from scratch my module => Did,'t work neither
I've updated composer and any dependencies / plugins (Limited by the Zend Framework version ofc)

Answer (score 0):

ok so... i figured it out. There is a Data/Cache Folder in the app with the modules classmap and configuration. These files were from 2020... I deleted it and Voilà ! It's working.
[See cache files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYzKA.png)